# Find alphanumeric value between two alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
create table #temp (SortValue varchar(100))
insert into #temp
values
('511111'),
('211'),
('HPA19'),
('IPA-255'),
('IPA-223'),
('HPA19GA')
```

I'd like to find only the values between HPA11 and HPA3237.

If I try:

```
select *
from #temp
where sortvalue between 'hpa11' and 'hpa3237'
```

I receive results:

```
HPA19,
HPA19GA
```

However, I'm trying to find a way for HPA19GA to NOT show up in my results.  I (think) I understand why SQL is returning this as a result between HPA11 and HPA3237.  However, in my data set I know that only HPA11 through HPA3237 and I need to know that HPA19GA is invalid and does not fall between my min/max values.

I have tried the following:

```
select *
from #temp
where right('0000000000' + sortvalue, 10)
between '00000hpa11' and '0000hpa237'
```

This returns
511111,
HPA19

```
I also tried:
select *
from #temp
where  SUBSTRING (sortvalue, PATINDEX ('% [0-9]%',sortvalue), LEN (sortvalue))
between 'HPA11' and 'HPA3237'
```

It returns:

```
HPA19GA
```

I also tried:

```
select *
from #temp
where left(concat(sortvalue, '0000000000'), 10)
between 'HPA1100000' and 'HPA3237000'
```

It Returns:

```
HPA19,
HPA19GA
```

If anyone has a brilliant idea I would love to see what someone could come up with!

Comment: You probably need to define what your comparison rules are that you're trying to achieve.
My best guess is that you want the alpha's and the numerics sorted differently. So you're actually trying to search between "HPA0011" and "HPA3237", in which case you need to do some string manipulation.
Maybe edit the post to put the values in the order you think the order is/should be.

Comment: Given your example data, what results do you want?

Comment: Why shouldn't it return in the results? What's your criteria for incllusion or exclusion?

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and looks at this.  I basically have a list of min/max values for a whole bunch of orders.  So we might have:
Part1:  Min: hpa11   Max:  hpa3237
Part2:  Min:  bg555  Max:  bg597
Part3:  Min:  A1        Max:  A11

As we are keying data we need to be alerted if someone keys Part1 / Value:  HPA19GA that it is invalid because it is not between HPA11 through 3237.

If they key Part3 / A17 we need to know it is invalid because it does not fall between A1 through 11.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to separate the `string` portion (`HGA`) from the numeric portion. Given your sample data, I believe this achieves your solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE 
  LEFT(SortValue, 3) = 'HPA' -- only consider values starting with HPA
  AND TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(SortValue, 4, LEN(SortValue)-3) AS INT) BETWEEN 11 AND 3237
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is actually a huge database with various alphanumeric circumstances.  I can't necessarily filter out just the 'HPA' rows...

I need to select all values in that table and know which are/are not between HPA11 and HPA3237

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed that.  If I specifically strip out the 'HPA', yes it works great.  But since I will have varying values they won't all have HPA.

If I try the script without stripping the HPA:

```

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE 
   TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(SortValue, 4, LEN(SortValue)-3) AS INT) BETWEEN 11 AND 3237
```

I receive results as:
511111,
HPA19